# JSZip compress image upload, encrypt, decrypt, display image

Tags: javascript, file-upload, compression, jszip, cryptico

Initially I was using FileReader to convert an image upload into base64 on the client side and then [encrypt](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico). Would attach that result to a form field and then submit but this is taking up way too much time so I'm looking for an alternative.

I'm trying to use [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html) to first compress and then encrypt and then submit, retrieve, decrypt, and show the image but I'm stuck on how to do that. My attempt to compress looks like this.

```js
$(document).on("change", "#chatImage", function() {
    var rid = $(this).closest(".chat").data("id");
    var tempSrc = $(this).val();
    /* Make a zip file here */
    var fi = $(this);
    var fileInput = fi;
    var files = [];
    // get all selected file
    $.each(fileInput.files, function(i, file) {
        files.push(file);
    });
    //create a zip object
    var zip = new JSZip();
    //add all files to zip 
    function addFileToZip(n) {
        if(n >= files.length) {
            //here generate file to zip on client side
            zip.generateAsync({type:"blob", compression:"default"}).then(function(content){
                //generated zip content to file type
                var files = new File([content], "default.zip");
                console.log(files);
                var eImgArray = {};
                $.ajax({
                    url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
                    type : 'post',
                    data : {
                    action: 'get_room_member_keys',
                    rid : rid,
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {},
                    success: function(html) {
                        var pubKeys = $.parseJSON(html);
                        $.each( pubKeys, function( key, value ) {
                            var imgEncrypt = cryptico.encrypt(files, value);
                            var imgSrc = imgEncrypt.cipher;
                            eImgArray[key] = imgSrc;
                        });
                        var strImgArray = JSON.stringify(eImgArray);
                    },
                });
            });
            return;
        }
        var file = files[n];                    
        var arrayBuffer;
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function() {
            arrayBuffer = this.result;
            zip.file(file.name, arrayBuffer);
            addFileToZip(n + 1);
        }
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
    addFileToZip(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="jaj3dm" class="chat" />
<input id="chatImage" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

This shows an encrypted string in the console and the result of compressing but when I decrypt and log the result to the console, I get nothing. What is the correct way to do this and or a better one?

Comment: This is way too incomplete for anyone to attempt to look at. Post at least a working fiddle with HTML so we can have a better idea to what are you trying to accomplish here

Comment: @MerakMarey I tried to turn their example into a Stack Snippet, but it's still horrible and over-complicated. Their problem boils down to overcomplicating absolutely everything.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 lol I'm not a professional developer and won't argue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've ridiculously overcomplicated this!

```js
$(document).on("change", "#chatImage", function() {
  var files = this.files;
  var zip = new JSZip();

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
    var file = files[i];
    zip.file(file.name, file);

    console.log("added", file.name);
  }

  console.log("generating zip…");
  zip.generateAsync({type: "blob"}).then(function(content) {
    console.log("done. creating download link");

    /* All that "sending to the interwebz" stuff */
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(content);
    link.innerText = "Download…";
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    /* display the uploaded images */
    function show_all_images(relpath, file) {
      console.log("showing", relpath);
      if (file.dir) {
        return file.forEach(show_all_images);
      }
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.alt = relpath;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
      file.async("blob").then(function(blob) {
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      });
    }
    new JSZip.loadAsync(content).then(zip => zip.forEach(show_all_images));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cryptico/0.0.1343522940/cryptico.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="chatImage" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

Comment: So I can zip and then encrypt and then decrypt and display the image? I think that's the part I'm confused about. Can you add the step mimicking retrieving that image from the file after I decrypt and adding it to an image tag? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have the encrypt/decrypt part. I just don't understand how to loop through image files in the zip and display them after I've decrypted the zip.

Comment: @user300979 I've just spent an hour trying to get the encryption / decryption to work. :-/ Maybe I should try reading. :-) I'll add that.

Comment: @user300979 I think that's everything now. If this solved your problem, please click the accept button. If you're completely, 100% sure this solved your problem completely and properly, please also award the bounty; usually people wait until it's expired before doing that, though, to increase the attention given to their question.

Comment: @user300979 Thanks! ☺

Comment: Yeap that does the trick. Great work and thanks for your time! This was a key piece for me.